# Insert ILoggingEvent into Database

Tags: java-8, logback

I'm using Logback library for logging all the client and server errors in my client-server application model. Now I have implemented a custom appender on the client to send the ILoggingEvent object to the server. Now I need to find a way to write the ILoggingEvent in the database like it was been send using the `logger.error("exception", "user", stacktrace);` function. How can I achieve this in Logback API?

Comment: how *much* did you search? You need a `DB Appender`, see here : https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

Comment: I cannot use a db appender because the client has only connection to the server. And the logging need to send to the server and the server will need to place the logs in the database without changing the data of the logs.

Comment: wouldn't that be expensive? Each log sending the data to some server? How about once you have the logs in a local file have a job that sends them to the server?